# Position of "double_buffer yes" in ~/.conkyrc

Tags: conky

According to the [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/conky), in the "Prevent flickering" section, the line "double_buffer yes" should be placed "below the other options, not below TEXT or XY".

But when I look at [Crunchbang default Conky](http://pastebin.com/Z0c8pCQW), there are several options (not TEXT or XY) below "double_buffer yes" (line 45).

So is the positioning of "double_buffer yes" not critical (so long as it is above TEXT or XY)?

Comment: Have you tried yourself? :-) Maybe it depends on the version of conky. The example was made in Feb. 2012 and the specific line that says to put "double_buffer yes" below the other options was added in Oct. 2010 https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Conky&diff=120068&oldid=119332.

Comment: Well, after reading John's reply, I moved that line to the top of my .conkyrc with no visible bad effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man conky` (online [here](http://conky.sourceforge.net/docs.html)) says:

> ```
>    double_buffer
>           Use the Xdbe extension? (eliminates flicker)  It  is
>           highly  recommended  to use own window with this one
>           so double buffer won't be so big.
> ```

There is nothing about placing the option below others.

Secondly, the official [`conky` FAQ on sourceforge](http://conky.sourceforge.net/faq.html) discusses double-buffering and nothing is said about placing the option below other options.

Third, conky's official list of [config settings on sourceforge](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html) mentions double buffering but says nothing about placing it after other options.

Fourth, my personal conky files have several option settings after the double buffering setting and it works for me.

I conclude that the Arch documentation is likely out of date.